# Git push creates my project folder inside another folder, how to avoid it?

Tags: github, ssh, repository, git-commit, git-push

I have been creating some repositories of my projects since the terminal and everything was good, but recently I tried to push a project to GitHub and but another folders are created.

For example, the path of my project folder is `/Desktop/Programming_course/React_Native/robotreact`.

So, since the terminal I go to the path of my Project `robotreact` and I run:

```sh
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Then, in GitHub, I create my repository and after that I run:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/Josesosa0777/robotreact.git
```

when I push it running: `git push -u origin main`

In my GitHub are created other folders:

[image: Folders]

How can I avoid those extra folders?

It seems like if another project is added, I am not sure if the problem is about a SSH key, I dont know how to solve it, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

That means you have initialized your Git repository in `/` instead of `/Desktop/Programming_course/React_Native/robotreact`: check for `/.git`

If that is the case, and you don't have many commits, you can simply:

- delete `/.git`
- initialize the repository in the right folder,
- add the remote origin
- add files, commit and push

That is:

```
cd /Desktop/Programming_course/React_Native/robotreact 
git init .
git remote add origin https://github.com/Josesosa0777/robotreact.git
# check your user.name/user.email
git config user.name
git config user.email
git add .
git commit -m "First import"
git push -u origin main
```

If your local branch is master:

```
git push -u origin master:main
```